# Creating several vectors with idiosyncratic length at once in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, apply

I want to create several vectors with different length containing 0. The lenght of the vectors differ and are stored in a vector kj.

```
k <- 12 # nr of vectors which might be changed
kj <- c(17, 2, 12,2,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7 ) # lenght per vector which might be changed
```

To be able to quickly adjust the number of vectors and their respective lenght, I thought about using `lapply()` or a `for loop`, but until now I did not find a way.

```
differences <- numeric() # starting object for storing vectors
  
for (i in 1:length(kj)){
  vec <- rep(0,kj[i]) 
  differences <- list(differences, vec)
}
```

gives out a very nested object and

```
lapply(0, rep, times = kj)
```

gives the error that `times` is an unvalid argument. I would prefer an object where I can access the vectors via `[i]` or `[[i]]` later. What is the easiest and shortest way to create it?
Thanks in advance, I am new in R and here and hope to be clear enough.

Comment: You could use `Map(rep, 0, kj)`.

Comment: In your `lapply` attempt, I think you meant to loop over 'kj': `lapply(kj, function(x) rep(0, x))`

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thank you. It was my first try with ```lapply```...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question: Map(rep, 0, kj) did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The `lapply` or `Map` approach is simpler but here is another way using `split` and `findInterval` generating all the 0's at once.

```
tmp <- rep(0, sum(kj))
split(tmp, findInterval(seq_along(tmp), cumsum(kj), left.open = TRUE))

#$`0`
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

#$`1`
#[1] 0 0

#$`2`
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

#$`3`
#[1] 0 0

#$`4`
#[1] 0 0

#$`5`
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#...
#...
```